# Realm of the Mad God migration?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I have a Realm of the Mad God account that i spent a lot of time on, I logged out of the account and made an alt and got that account to an archer. When i logged out of that account and logged back into my main, it said account migration. so i pressed yes. after that I logged back onto my main and the whole thing was reset to default. i lost all of my items and the time i spent on the game. is there any way i can get that data back. I have tried resetting the password and logging in and out of the account, but it still is default. The account is under the same email, but it is reset to default. Can someone give me clarification, and a way to get my account back?

Thank you,
Ian

Comment: Where was your account from?  Kongregate? Or the Steam version?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [contacting support](http://decagames.desk.com/customer/portal/emails/new), but other than that I don't think that you can get your stuff back. Sorry :(

Comment: Thanks for responding, great answer! I did contact support and they haven't gotten back yet. I'm not sure what will happen, I checked Reddit on the migration, and it said my stuff will come back in a couple of days. But that post was posted years ago...